# Construct structured numpy array from a file?

Tags: python, file, numpy, structured-array

I've been given the task of writing a simple MD-Simulation program in python which does not utilize python builtin types (dict, list) but only numpy arrays. From what I understood, this allows the code to be compiled to run faster. At one point in my code, I want to get the mass of an atom from a dictionary-like object, that can be sliced by the element name like `MassDict['N'] = 14.0067`.

From what I've read, I'd need to use a structured numpy array. What I want to do right now is open my file with the following form:

```
H 1.008
He 4.003
Li 6.941
```

and then construct a structured numpy array, which can be sliced by using the element names in the first column.

I tried making two numpy arrays and then concatenating them, but that doesn't seem to be what I need. My code looks not that great to begin with. So how do I create a numpy object which can be sliced by string from a text file optimally?
Here's my code:

```py
import numpy as np
import re

def mass_el(file):

    with open(file) as inf:

        for i, line in enumerate(inf):
            pass

        elements = np.empty((i+1),dtype='S2')
        masses = np.empty((i+1),dtype=np.float32)


    with open(file) as inf:

        for i, line in enumerate(inf):
            elements[i] = re.search('[a-zA-Z]+',line).group()
            masses[i] = re.search('\d+[.]\d+',line).group()

    #???


mass_el('elements.txt')
```

Comment: How many entries do you have in total? Only those three?

Comment: that's what the first ```with open... pass``` is for. It counts the lines and creates ```np.empty``` arrays with the appropriate number of entries. Did I mess up the indent while copying my code? I think the arrays need to be one indent to the left...

Comment: But how many do you have in total? If its only three, a `dict` makes most likely more sense than an `np.ndarray`

Comment: 108 entries of Element Mass. Btw I can't use python builtins because they can't be accelerated by a compiler apparently.

Comment: Or you straight up use something like [mendeleev](https://mendeleev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html): `from mendeleev import H; H.atomic_weight  # 1.008`

Comment: That would work, but I'd like to know how to do something like that in general since it might come up again when I can't simply import a convenient module which contains all the data I need.

Comment: Are you required to use such a format? If not you could save constants like these in `.py` files as a dict and import the file, and save large arrays as NumPy `.npy` files.

Comment: You may gave misunderstood the reason for using `numpy`.  Used right those arrays are faster because they use compiled code. But wrong uses (iterative) are slower.  Good code uses lists and dictionaries where appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

#### Using numpy

You could use the [numpy loadtxt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) function, which allows you to read and format directly from a file your data, if the data fields in the file are regularly separated (a CSV file).

```
m_els = np.loadtxt('elements.txt', dtype={'names':('element', 'mass'), 'formats':('U2', 'f')})
```

Using your 3-lines file, you get the following `m_els` array:

```
array([('H', 1.008), ('He', 4.003), ('Li', 6.941)],
    dtype=[('element', '<U2'), ('mass', '<f4')])
```

Which is what you want I guess. To get an element, say hydrogen, do `m_els[0]` to get the first tuple. `m_els[0][1]` to get the hydrogen mass.

#### Using pandas

It's even easier using `pandas` which is also fast since it's builtd on top of `numpy`.

```
import pandas as pd
m_els = pd.read_csv('elements.txt', sep='\s+', header=None, names=['element', 'mass'])
```

In this case `m_els` is a dataframe, where element names are used as indexes:

```
  element   mass
0       H  1.008
1      He  4.003
2      Li  6.941
```

To get the row corresponding to an element, say hydrogen, do `m_els.iloc[0]`. To get the hydrogen mass, do `m_els.loc[0, 'mass']` or, using the element name, `m_els['mass'].loc[m_els['element'] == 'H']`.

Comment: `m_els['mass'][0]` gets the mass of the first entry. This looks like the right structured array, but I don't see how it's an improvement over a dict.

Comment: Me neither honestly, but the OP asked explicitly how to do this with numpy and to not use dictionaries.

Comment: As I said, I'm new to type casting (only used python up until this point and I was surprised to learn about memory allocation). So I don't know how a certain object type influences preformance and how well you can speed it up with a compiler. Is it not really impactful, so I can just use a dict?

Comment: That depends on how you are using these data structures. If you just need to pick the correct mass few times, a dictionary is perfectly fine. If you need to do vectorized calculation (like picking all the masses as a vector and perform some stuff) then better to use numpy. Will be faster than writing a `for` loop to collect all the masses from your dictionary.